# flying saucer / jruby on rails generate pdf from view

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, flying-saucer

I am trying to generate a pdf from a view in jruby on rails using flying saucer with the following code in the controller:

```
def calendar
  @patient = Patient.find_by_id(params[:id])
  result = render_to_string
  send_data( FlyingSaucer::create_pdf(result), :filename => "calendar.pdf",
           :type => "application/pdf",
           :disposition => 'attachment')
end
```

I am getting an error

> uninitialized constant PatientsController::FlyingSaucer

I am requiring java and flying_saucer in the controller

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest trying to knock together a little stand-alone script and see if you can re-create the problem (and if so, post it here!)

Comment: alright I've eliminated all the error messages, but now the server just hangs when the calendar action is called.

Comment: Can you re-create in a stand-alone script?  Can you describe the steps you took to fix the uninitialized constant error (for the benefit of others who might come across this)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require 'flying_saucer'
java_import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer

class SomeController < ApplicationController

def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { send_data render_pdf, :filename => 'test.pdf' }
  end
end

private

def render_pdf                                                                
  io = StringIO.new                                                           
 content = render_to_string(:layout => false)
 # content = '<html><body><h1>Yo</h1></body></html>'                         
 renderer = ITextRenderer.new                                                
 renderer.set_document_from_string(content)                                  
 renderer.layout                                                             
 renderer.create_pdf(io.to_outputstream)                                     
 io.string                                                                   
 end                                                                           
end 

end
```

Try looking at slide 66 of this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/nicksieger/sieger-eyconnectingjavaruby) for an example.

[This](https://bosmeeuw.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/jruby-on-rails-pdf-generation-and-flying-saucers/) might also be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the flying saucer jars are in the classpath.